TFS GlobalList imported by mistake, is there any way to revert?
I have a collection with 10 projects (Lets say CollectionA).
By mistake I ran the global list import command instead of export with a different global.xml file of other collection (CollectionB). What will happen in that case?
Will that overwrite the whole existing list of CollectionA? or Append the content of my global.xml (CollectionB) to the collectionB which I used to run the import command?

What detailed commands did you mistakenly use to run the global list import? Can you provide the detailed steps you did?

witadmin exportgloballist /collection:"$URL/DefaultCollection" /f:"c:\GlobalList\global.xml"

In this command the global.xml was of different collection.

Did you go the web page of CollectionA to check if the previous global lists are still existing, or just add the new global lists from the mistakenly executed witadmin importgloballist command? @KaleshEs

@BrightRan-MSFT executed by mistake.

Have you gone to the web page of CollectionA to check whether the current global lists are correct? In addition, does any of the mistakenly imported global lists has the same list name or list item name as that in the previous global lists? @KaleshEs
